# How do we compute the rational cohomology ring $H^*\left(\bigsqcup_{i\ge 1}S^n;\mathbb{Q}\right)$?

Tags: ring-theory, homology-cohomology

> How do we compute the rational cohomology ring $H^*\left(\bigsqcup_{i\ge 1}S^n;\mathbb{Q}\right)$?

*Thoughts*: Clearly, this is $H^*\left(\bigsqcup_{i\ge 1}S^n;\mathbb{Q}\right)\cong \prod_{i\ge 1}H^*(S^n;\mathbb{Q})$. I am not sure where to go from here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what there is *left* to say. The ring $H^*(S^n;\Bbb Q)$ has a generator in degree $0$ (call it $1$), a generator in degree $n$ (call it $\alpha$) and $\alpha^2 = 0$, $1 \cdot \alpha = \alpha$. It is the exterior algebra on a single generator. In the right hand side now you have $\prod_{i \geq 1} \Bbb Z$ in degree $0$ and $n$, so each element is written as $\sum a_{j} 1_j$ (where $a_j \in \Bbb Z$) in degree 0, and each element is written $\sum b_j \alpha_j$ in degree $n$. If $i \neq j$, then $1_i \cdot 1_j = 1_i \cdot \alpha_j = 0$. Otherwise the relations are the same as above.

Comment: (All I have written out is the definition of infinite product of rings very explicitly.)